# Unable to run C# application with Microsoft Graph 3.2.0 due to issues with system.net.http missing reference

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api

```
system.net.http
```

- NuGet: 4.3.4 -> 4.0.30319 -> 4.1.1.3
- NuGet: 4.3.3 -> 4.0.30319 -> 4.1.1.2
- NuGet: 4.3.2 -> 4.0.30319 -> 4.1.1.1
- Framework: 4.6.2 > 4.0.30319 -> 4.0.0.0

[image]

Now, if I change my project settings like this to 4.7.2:

[image]

And then examine my `system.net.http assembly`:

[image]

- Framework: 4.7.2 > 4.0.30319 -> 4.2.0.0

So the above research implies that if I want `system.net.http` I need to use the **.NET Framework 4.7.2**. OK so far. But ...

**Microsoft Graph 3.2.0**
When you look at the dependencies for Microsoft Graph 3.2.0 it says:

[image]

So it is stating that it depends on **.NET Framework 4.6.1** right?

So I uninstall and re-install several NuGet Packages so that they are right for 4.7.2 and then I modify my `app.config` entry:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Now it compiles. Yet, when I run the software I still except this exception (found everywhere on the internet!):

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"}

That file I believe is here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net471\lib

That is the one used during complilation.

Yet when I try to find the runtime path to this DLL all I can find is:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

But the file in there is dated 19/03/2019 with a file version of 4.8.3752.0. Yet the one in here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net471\lib

Is 01/04/2020 version 4.6.26011.1.

So I am utterly confused. **Microsoft Graph 3.2.0** says it is dependent on **.NET Framework 4.6.1** yet it complains about requiring **`system.net.http` 4.2.0.0** and despite having .NET Framework 4.7.2 installed I have all this mess.

I never had issues using Microsoft Graph in the past and it is only because I upgraded to their latest libraries via NuGet Manager that my tool is utterly broken.

I have tried all of the suggestions found on SO about binding redirects and deleting old files. I just don't why Microsoft Graph says it is dependent on 4.6.1 yet the exception said it needed (and couldn't find 4.2.0.0 which is Framework 4.7.2).

I kindly appreciate any specific steps to resolve this issue so that my application will not only compile again but actually work like it used to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled over this [question](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24382) and based on the comments it said that my app.config needed to be:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Since the Microsoft Graph package is dependent on .NET Framework 4.6.1 we need to be using the 4.0.0.0 `system.net.http` else we get the conflict errors.

Sorted.